# Pinout for 3.5mm female audio jack

Tags: audio, connector, pinout

Whats the pinout for this jack?
[image]

Comment: I'd assume it's exactly as it looks?

Comment: @mmmm where is the ground, left and right?

Comment: Ah, this is not about *this* connector in specific, but about 3.5mm TRS in general! You can see which contacts connect to the tip, ring and sleeve of the 3.5 mm Jack, so where exactly does that question arise? I'm a bit confused, 3.5 mm is well documented?

Comment: @mmmmi instead of testing it that way i am asking if there is some kind of pinout diagram already because i cant find something like this on the internet

Comment: Do you have one with you?

Comment: There is. Surely, I'm not the only for whom googling for '3.5 mm pinout' returns image results that answer that question instantly?

Comment: @HandyHowie yes

Comment: Can’t you plug a male connector in and use a multimeter to work it out?

Comment: @mmmm it doesn't return any image result for the pinout of the connecter which i show.

Comment: You can **see** on your photos which pads connect to which part of the jack. Seriously.

Comment: @HandyHowie i dont have any male connectors lying around.

Comment: @mmmm could you send the link of an image. I cant find any

Comment: Surely, imagining that the most behind contact contacts the tip of the jack isn't that hard? And the next connecting the ring? And then there's not much left? As said, three times now, your photo actually shows the contacts where they connect to the male jack when you plug it in? It's directly visible in your photo!

Comment: @mmmm No i didn't say i could. HandyHowie asked if i have one with you and i guessed that he was talking about havng he female connector

Comment: @mmmm but why does it have 5 pins? Which one is which. I am confused and i dont want to make any mistakes

Comment: Look at the metal parts of your connector. Again, you can *see* where they meet the connector. You can really see that! And you can see which pads are connected!

Comment: It is a surface mount device. i count four pads not five. And two of those appear to be the same piece of bent metal.

Comment: Looking closely at the two examples in the photo, they appear to have different solder pin layouts. Which pinout are you asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector nearest the socket is ground. The connector farthest from the socket is the centre pin. The one in the middle is... you guessed it. But you are probably aware of that.

That accounts for three of the surface mount pins. The fourth forms a single-pole switch contact to the centre pin connector. When there is no plug, the two contacts meet. But when you plug in the male, it pushes the centre contact up, breaking the connection to the fourth pin, which is now open circuit. This can be used by the electronics to wait until the male is pushed home before activating, thus helping to protect a sensitive input circuit from damage during insertion or removal.

Comment: Some have a normally-open plug detection switch, rather than the normally-closed one you talk about here. But most of them are NC in my experience, yes.

Comment: @Hearth There are, or once were, several variations on the theme. My answer describes the contact arrangement illustrated in the question (though the two switches shown appear to have different layouts, not sure why).